# How to list subcollections in a Cloud Firestore document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Say I have this minimal database stored in Cloud Firestore. How could I retrieve the names of `subCollection1` and `subCollection2`?

```
rootCollection {
    aDocument: {
        someField: { value: 1 },
        anotherField: { value: 2 }
        subCollection1: ...,
        subCollection2: ...,
    }
}
```

I would expect to be able to just read the ids off of `aDocument`, but only the fields show up when I `get()` the document.

```js
rootRef.doc('aDocument').get()
  .then(doc =>

    // only logs [ "someField", "anotherField" ], no collections
    console.log( Object.keys(doc.data()) )
  )
```

Comment: Aren't collections supposed to be known to the programmer beforehand? What is your use case?

Comment: @VictorNascimento. The use case is dealing with the lack of recursive deletion. I'm trying to delete a document with subcollections in it, and those subcollections should be deleted too because they are children of the document and no longer valid. Yes, at the moment I happen to know the names of the collections, but it would be terrible practice to need to enumerate by hand every single subcollection on a tree of potentially infinite depth just to delete a single document.

Comment: Sub-collections are not members/properties of the parent document that is used to reference them.

Comment: Recursive deletion can be done in the Admin SDK and via the CLI. See doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections).

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76654434/2126077

Answer (score 6):

It is not currently supported to get a list of (sub)collections from Firestore in the client SDKs (Web, iOS, Android). From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document):

> Retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web client libraries. You should only look up collection names as part of administrative tasks in trusted server environments. If you find that you need this capability in the mobile/web client libraries, consider restructuring your data so that subcollection names are predictable.

In **server-side SDKs** this functionality *does* exist. For example, in Node.js you'll be after the `ListCollectionIds` method:

```
var firestore = require('firestore.v1beta1');

var client = firestore.v1beta1({
  // optional auth parameters.
});

// Iterate over all elements.
var formattedParent = client.anyPathPath("[PROJECT]", "[DATABASE]", "[DOCUMENT]", "[ANY_PATH]");

client.listCollectionIds({parent: formattedParent}).then(function(responses) {
    var resources = responses[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < resources.length; ++i) {
        // doThingsWith(resources[i])
    }
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Not exactly good news, but at least it's coming. Thanks for the update. Any suggestions on currently available techniques for recursive deletion on documents with subcollections?

Comment: @Dan McGrath Is firestore just cloud-datastore rebranded?

Comment: @skylize -> Trigger a Cloud Function to perform it.

Comment: @DimuDesigns -> No.

Comment: @Dan McGrath How does triggering a cloud function help? Are you saying `ListCollectionIds` is available _now_ in Cloud Functions?

Comment: Cloud Functions allows you to use the Node.js server client library (see code in my answer).

Comment: I tried installing `@google-cloud/firestore`, but my client does not have `anyPathPath()` or `ListCollectionIdsMethods`. I tried installing `firestore.v1beta1`, but not found in `npm` registry. I tried importing `firestore` and `firestore.v1beta1` and `@google-cloud/firestore.v1beta1` but none of them is a resolvable module.

Comment: Oh, this is my first "write-only" database. Or should I call it "black-hole" database? :-(

Comment: @DanMcGrath When Firestore is enabled in the GCP console, the Cloud Datastore tab links to the Firebase console with the statement "Cloud Firestore is the next generation of Cloud Datastore..." . Will Cloud Firestore be replacing Cloud Datastore at some point in the future?

Answer (score 5):

It seems like they have added a method called `getCollections()` to Node.js:

```
firestore.doc(`/myCollection/myDocument`).getCollections().then(collections => {
  for (let collection of collections) {
    console.log(`Found collection with id: ${collection.id}`);
  }
});
```

This example prints out all subcollections of the document at `/myCollection/myDocument`

Comment: That looks promising. I had to give up on using Firestore because of this issue, and have not had a chance to give it another try. I hope my question led to a better experience for others. And if this is fixed, as you suggest, then I hope I have a chance to try it again.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#node.js_6)

Sadly the docs aren't clear what you import.

Based on the docs, my code ended up looking like this:

```
import admin, { firestore } from 'firebase-admin'

let collections: string[] = null
const adminRef: firestore.DocumentReference<any> = admin.firestore().doc(path)
const collectionRefs: firestore.CollectionReference[] = await adminRef.listCollections()
collections = collectionRefs.map((collectionRef: firestore.CollectionReference) => collectionRef.id)
```

This is of course Node.js server side code. As per the docs, this cannot be done on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this detailed in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data)?

> ```
> /**
>  * Delete a collection, in batches of batchSize. Note that this does
>  * not recursively delete subcollections of documents in the collection
>  */
> function deleteCollection(db, collectionRef, batchSize) {
>     var query = collectionRef.orderBy('__name__').limit(batchSize);
>
>     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
>         deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject);
>     });
> }
>
> function deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject) {
>     query.get()
>         .then((snapshot) => {
>             // When there are no documents left, we are done
>             if (snapshot.size == 0) {
>                 return 0;
>             }
>
>             // Delete documents in a batch
>             var batch = db.batch();
>             snapshot.docs.forEach(function(doc) {
>                 batch.delete(doc.ref);
>             });
>
>             return batch.commit().then(function() {
>                 return snapshot.size;
>             });
>         }).then(function(numDeleted) {
>             if (numDeleted <= batchSize) {
>                 resolve();
>                 return;
>             }
>
>             // Recurse on the next process tick, to avoid
>             // exploding the stack.
>             process.nextTick(function() {
>                 deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject);
>             });
>         })
>         .catch(reject);
> }
> ```

Comment: Of all the code you posted here, the only part relevant to my question is the comment at the top, "this does not recursively delete subcollections of documents in the collection". My specific intended use case was to manually recurse the subcollections so I could delete them using the instructions in the docs. Yet for some crazy reason I can't get a list of the subcollections to know what to delete.

Comment: have you figured something out?

Comment: `doc.data().someField.subCollection1` or `doc.data().someField.subCollection1.val()` or `doc.data().someField.subCollection1.val`?