# Firestore - Get document collections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would automate the backup process of a firestore database.

The idea is to loop over the root document to build a JSON tree, but I didn't find a way to get all collections available for a document. I guess it's possible as in firestore console we can see the tree.

Any ideas?

- ref doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore

Comment: Here's the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73411426/1205871

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the Node.js server SDK you can use the `getCollections()` method on `DocumentReference`:
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.8.x/DocumentReference#getCollections

This method will return a promise for an array of `CollectionReference` objects which you can use to access the documents within the collections.

Comment: I can't find anything similar on the Web side (JavaScript in browser). Is it just me, or?

Comment: That's correct, this is only implemented in the server-side SDKs for now.

Comment: I just noticed that it is possible to run code on the server side. This will run on Node.js. Would it be possible to use this now to call getCollections() and output the result to the client?

Comment: Web-side I've have implemented the following workaround:
db.collection(firstCollections + '/' + docId + '/' + subCollection).get()
for obtaining documents in 'subCollection'

Comment: @SamStern Is there a plan to add this feature to the client side SDKs? It's really inconvenient and potentially expensive to have to use a cloud function to simply traverse the document tree. Major drawback if switching from Firebase, almost a non-starter

Answer (score 13):

Its possible on web (client side js)

```
db.collection('FirstCollection/' + id + '/DocSubCollectionName').get().then((subCollectionSnapshot) => {
    subCollectionSnapshot.forEach((subDoc) => {
        console.log(subDoc.data());
    });
});
```

Thanks to @marcogramy comment

Answer (score 11):

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const db = firebase.firestore();

db.settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true});

const collection = db.collection('user_dat');

collection.get().then(snapshot => {

  snapshot.forEach(doc => {

    console.log( doc.data().name );    
    console.log( doc.data().mail );

  });

});
```

Answer (score 8):

**Update**
API has been updated, now function is .listCollections()
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#listCollections

---

[getCollections()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.8.x/DocumentReference#getCollections) method is available for NodeJS.

Sample code:

```
    db.collection("Collection").doc("Document").getCollections().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((collection) => {
        console.log("collection: " + collection.id);
        });
    });
```

Comment: API has been updated, now function is `.listCollections()`, https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#listCollections . Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/57248728/2162226.  This got me going in right direction, Thanks

Comment: I cannot find this for Flutter

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, on the server side you can use `getCollections().` To get all the root-level collections, use it on the db like so:

```
const serviceAccount = require('service-accout.json');
const databaseURL = 'https://your-firebase-url-here';
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: databaseURL
});
const db = admin.firestore();
db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });
db.getCollections().then((snap) => {
    snap.forEach((collection) => {
        console.log(`paths for colletions: ${collection._referencePath.segments}`);
    });
});
```

Comment: Till now client-side js doesn't have getCollections function

Comment: Hence I said "on the server side" but see update to API in Mike Yang's answer that lets the client side use `listCollections()`