# How to list all Document collections in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to list all collections of a DocumentReference? I found old questions but all answers are outdated by Firestore SDK or require that I already know the name of collections.

ref: [Firestore - Get document collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46989568/firestore-get-document-collections)

Comment: I'm not a Firebase expert, but have you tried [this method](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/DocumentReference#getCollections) with `let documentRef = firestore.doc('/');` ? It's in the latest version docs

Comment: Nothing has changed.  You still can't list subcollections from a client, and it's not likely that you'll be able to do so in the future.