# Why ref.getCollections() is not recognized as a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase

I'm doing a website which store users data on cloud firestore. I use this to get all subcollections of a user document once:

```
db.collection('users').doc(userID).getCollections().then( collections => {
  /*I get my collections and I enjoy it :D*/
})
```

The problem is that this function is not recognized. I find this message on the console:

```
TypeError: db.collection(...).doc(...).getCollections is not a function
```

I know I could get the all subcollections otherwise but I want to save the maximum of readings because of de limited quota. All others firebase functions work in my project (like `get()` or `set()`) and `getCollections()` is in the documentation.
Thank for your help !

Comment: Are you sure this is in Node.js? [The web client does not have the `getCollections()` method, but the Node.js client does](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document).

Comment: I use React. But maybe I have to import something ? I don't know.

Comment: @ValentinGegoux so you're writing in Node.js, but it's being compiled and served as static assets to the browser... so that means you are indeed using the firebase web client, which does not have `getCollections`. That's why I asked if you were sure it's Node.js :P

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you *use* node.js. What matter is where this code JavaScript runs. If it runs in a browser, the error message is expected as there is no `getCollections()` in the client-side SDKs. If this code runs server-side in a Node.js script, it might depend on the version of the Firebase Admin SDK that you're using. Right now there isn't enough information for us to determine which of these it is, or if it's maybe something else altogether.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I did some researches and I begin to understand. I do not use the Firebase Admin SDK but the client SDK (the most basic, I guess) and I don't use any server or other Node environment. So my code runs on client-side. That means, according to the doc, that I shouldn't try to use this function. Have you another way to get subcollections once ? I could get each subcollections of each user, but it's too much reads...

Comment: Oh, I learned that firebase is not designed to do this. I will try to change my organization... thanks again !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google team was replaced method name from 'getCollections' to 'listCollections'. So you should update this method name again.
Reference at here https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#listCollections

It works for me with these tool versions: firebase-tools v7.2.1, firebase-admin v8.3.0, firebase-functions v3.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

In your example db.collection('users').doc(userID) returns DocumentReference
and as far I can see DocumentReference object doesn't support getCollections method

Here is the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference