# retrieving multiple documents from firestore

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firestore. I have problem in retrieving multiple documents from firestore. Please help me.

My database is like following:

```
Trips --> User_id1 --> Date1 --> place_id --> place name
          User_id2     Date2                  place address
                       Date3
```

I have to access till place name

And my code is:

```
db.collection("Trips").document(mAuth.getUid()).get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        // as there are multiple dates under one user id so we need loop here. but how?
                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: How did you put the dates under a user/trip document? Is it a nested collection? Or a map of values?

Comment: Check my database.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ytjxcb_7fHO1ErJBvhyuoj0TZcq-jAjI

Answer (score 0):

If you *know* what collection you want to access, you can do so with:

```
db.collection("Trips").document(mAuth.getUid()).collection("28-Nov-2017").get()...
```

There is no API to get a list of those collections.  So if you want to loop through the collections, you will have to define the valid collection names in some way (e.g. store the dates you have sub-collections for in the document).

Comment: No actually i have to retrieve data for all dates.

Comment: There is currently no API in the SDKs to get a list of the collections/sub-collections. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596532/how-to-list-subcollections-in-a-cloud-firestore-document. You could iterate all valid dates and check for docs in each potential collection. But that sounds wasteful on the number of calls.