# Google Cloud Function to iterate collection in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing cloud function to auto increase counter to track feedback. I am trying to iterate collection created from cloud function and increase counter if the answer is equal.

What I want to achieve with cloud function is to tracks firestore oncreate method call on "surveyfeedbacks" and add to "answerresult" collections if answer doesn't exist or increase counter if answer exist in "answerresult" collection. Please help me understand how to achieve it or can you advice if I doing it wrong?

[image: My Feedbacks data]

I can add new collection to "answerresult" collection but I don't know how to iterate collections with unique id in answerresults

[image: New Data to answerresult]

This is my code function to track and add new data.

[image: Code]

Comment: There is currently no API in the SDKs to iterate over collections. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596532/how-to-list-subcollections-in-a-cloud-firestore-document

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can i do this use case with Firebase real time database?