# Firestore get sub-collection of dynmically generated id?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have the following data needs.

The root collection is named **userData** which is the root node/collection.

Inside it, I have created documents which have **dynamic ids**. Note here that the document does not have any fields, but has two subcollections named **accountData** and **personalData**. Both of these collections have fields and data in them which I want to query and use.

So to query one user data I have to do the following

```
afs.collection('userData').doc('tbpSmHireUd').collection('accountData').snapshotChanges()
```

As you can see that the doc() has dynamically generated ids.

I am using AngularFire2 so kindly suggest a solution for that.

How can I get data from such a nested collection?

Also, do let me know whether I am formatting my data correctly?

Thanks

Comment: This code should work fine with a dynamically generated document ID: `afs.collection('userData').doc('tbpSmHireUd').collection('accountData')`. What's the problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am trying to get it for all docs. I will not know the id of each one. I want to list data from accountData for each parent doc with dynamic id.

Comment: Are you asking how to [get all documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is there an AngularFire2 getter for that?

Comment: here it is https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document Listing of subcollection is not possible. I was generating subcollections `accountData` on doc with dynamic ids. Using the get() method I get the data in doc but not subcollections. Which is a huge pain!

Comment: From your example, you already know the name of the sub-collections.  You just need to `get` all documents from them.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JasonBerryman No, it was just an example. I was wondering how to get them if I do not know them.

Comment: From what you said so far, I gather that `tbpSmHireUd` is meant to be the **variable** document ID, and `accountData` is a **fixed** collection name. There is indeed no client-side API to list collections, but there is a client-side API to list documents - as shown in the link I shared. If that doesn't work for you, please share some more of the code you tried. Right now were spending too much effort trying to understand each other in words, code is more likely to get us to a mutual understanding faster.

Comment: If indeed your question is how to list all subcollections under a specific document your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/46597126/209103