# Get Nested Docs in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my data:

[image]

I want to iterate through each `event_prod` in `event_prods` and go to the `eventGroups` subcollection. Once in that sub-collection, I want to loop through each `eventGroup` in `eventGroups` and get doc data.

Here's my code thus far:

```
async function getAllEventGroups() {
  let eventGroups = []

  try {
    let eventProducerRef = await db.collection('event_prods')
    let allEventProducers = eventProducerRef.get().then(
      producer => {
        producer.forEach(doc => console.log(doc.collection('eventGroups'))
      }
    )
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`get(): there be an error ${error}`)
    return []
  }
  return eventGroups
}
```

Obviously, it doesn't do what I want, but I can't figure out how to get access to the `eventGroups` subcollection. Calling 'collection()' on 'doc' is undefined. Can someone please help fix this? By the way, I don't care if this requires two (or more) queries as long as I don't have to bring in data I will never use.

Edit: this is not a duplicated because I know the name of my subcollection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list subcollections in a Cloud Firestore document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596532/how-to-list-subcollections-in-a-cloud-firestore-document)

Comment: @DougStevenson no these are two completely different issues. I know the name of my subcollection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the `.collection` on the [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot). This methods doesn't exist there. But as the [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) extends [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) you can call `ref` on it to get the reference to the requested document.

```

```
let allEventProducers = eventProducerRef.get().then(
      producer => {
        producer.forEach(doc => console.log(doc.ref.collection('eventGroups')) // not the ref here
      }
    )
```

Comment: so I added each ref to an array. Now I want to iterate through that array to get each document for those event Groups. How do I do that?

Comment: This answer is not sufficient as you cannot then `get()` collection data because `forEach` doesn't support promises.

Comment: @MartinD the answer was on how to get to the point where you can access subcollections. Yes, `forEach` can't handle promises, but you can map into an array of promises and then call `Promise.all()` on it. Problem solved, hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

`eventProducerRef` is a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference).  The [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) method on that yields a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot), which you are storing in `producer`.  When you iterate it with [forEach()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#forEach), you are getting a series of [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) objects, which you're storing in `doc`.  QueryDocumentSnapshot doesn't have a method called `collection()`, as you are trying to use right now.

If you want to reach into a subcollection of a document, build a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) to the document, then call its [collection()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#collection) method.  You'll need to use the id of each document for this.  Since a QueryDocumentSnapshot subclasses [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot), you can use its [id](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#~id) property for this:

```
let eventProducerRef = await db.collection('event_prods')
let allEventProducers = eventProducerRef.get().then(
  producer => {
    producer.forEach(snapshot => {
      const docRef = eventProducerRef.doc(snapshot.id)
      const subcollection = docRef.collection('eventGroups')
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: I think this is the same as the above.

Comment: This answer is not sufficient as you cannot then `get()` collection data because `forEach` doesn't support promises.