# How to get sub-collections with Firebase firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am tying to get all the collections withing the withing the document, I don't know how to do it I am new to firestore.

```
Firebase.firestore()
      .collection("reservations")
      .doc(tripUid)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        console.log(doc.doc.data());
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
```

[My Firebase firestore data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnrbp.png)

Comment: There is no API to get a list of all subcollections in the client-side SDKs of Cloud Firestore. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596532/how-to-list-subcollections-in-a-cloud-firestore-document

Comment: I only see a single collection under `Ab8F ... 8AJC` document. Where are you saying that are more than one?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So sub collections still follow the whole path idea of Firestore. So to give an example let's say you have a collection called 'Orders' with a sub collection called 'Products.' To get all the product documents of a specific Order you would write something like `Firebase.firestore().collection("Orders/orderid123/Products").get()` where orderid123 is the ID of the order you want the products for.

Looking at your data model, you have actually named the sub collection what appears to be a generated ID. So in the above example instead of using 'Products' you would instead be using 'ymuIjdv...'. You may want to revisit how you are naming this sub collection to give it a more human readable name. It looks like you are generating the ID for the sub collection document and using it as the name of the sub collection as well.

In your exact set up, what you are asking can be achieved by doing `Firebase.firestore().collection("reservations/" + tripUid + "/ymuIjdvwWnOr20XWVp6gwRKtmgD2").get()`. This will get all the sub collection documents under the reservation with an held within tripUid variable and within the collection 'ymuIjdvwWnOr20XWVp6gwRKtmgD2'.

Comment: thankyou. your solution worked. just wanteds to ask how do get all the orders from firestore. whole collection consisting sub collections. tried firebase.firestore().collection("orders").get() but it doesnt work.

Comment: Hi there. With the new version of Firebase, how would this be?

Comment: This finally helped 'how to access subcollections' click in my brain.

I was trying to get a document, then use that document to get collections, but I should just use it to create a path to the collection. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This is implementation for Firebase Admin SDK

Hope this will help

```
firestore()
    .collection("reservations")
    .doc(tripUid)
    .listCollections()
    .then((subCollections) => {
        subCollections.forEach((subCollection) => {
            subCollection
                .get()
                .then((array) => {
                    array.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                        console.log(doc.data());
                    });
                });
        });
    });
```