# Get all documents from collection in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get all posts from my 'instagram' clone app. This is the path I have in firestore: `posts > (unique ownerId) > userPosts > (unique postId)`

How can I retrieve all posts using a stream builder? I tried doing so with

```
body:
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: postsRef.snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return circularProgress();
            }
            List<Post> posts = snapshot.data.documents.map((doc) =>  Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
            return ListView(children: posts);
          },
        )
```

I want to display only the posts' pictures in a stack of cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use wildcards with listeners in Cloud Firestore.  You need to name the specific document and collections in the path.  So, if your `(unique ownerId)` is unknown at the time of the query, you will not be able to know anything about the documents changing in its subcollections.

As an alternative, on a backend you control, you can [list subcollections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596532/how-to-list-subcollections-in-a-cloud-firestore-document) of a document, then query those documents.  Or, you can use a Cloud Functions trigger and notify interested client apps (maybe with Cloud Messaging) as changes happen.