# How to get dynamic collection name from google-cloud-firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, redux-firestore

I have database. which each user create collection and collection name will be UID of users to save their data. 
[image]
I am using redux to manage state. this is my RootReducer ...

```
import {firestoreReducer} from 'redux-firestore'
import {firebaseReducer} from 'react-redux-firebase'

const RootReducer =combineReducers({
    firebase:firebaseReducer,
    firestore:firestoreReducer,
})
export default RootReducer;
```

here i get data from database and store it to "notes" and then passed to react component. notes: state.firestore.ordered."here should be collection name", but i have different collection for each users so the collection name should be dynamic according to the users UID . but i don't know how to do that? is this possible ?? thanks for any help..

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
  return{
        firebases:state.firebase.auth,
        notes:state.firestore.ordered.aAPocPrkXBgRalhu3zuTxSPxdn12 //this is collection name but i want to be dynamic :D
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
    return {

    }
}
export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps),
firestoreConnect(props=>{
    return [{collection:props.firebases.uid,orderBy:['createdAt','desc']}]}))(NotesScreen);
```

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to get a list of the sub-collection names? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596532/how-to-list-subcollections-in-a-cloud-firestore-document. Key in this answer is **"This is not currently supported in the client SDKs (Web, iOS, Android)."** To access a collection, you must already know the collection name from somewhere else, either hardcoded (most common), or because you have the UID elsewhere.

Comment: really i meant to get list of main collection names not sub-collections. anyway thank you so much.

Comment: The same applies to both top-level and subcollections: in the client-side SDKs you must know the collection name. Only the server-side SDKs have a way to get a list of (sub)collections. If you can't know something, make them a list of documents in a collection (with a known name), not a list of collections.

Comment: Ok I understood Thank you so much.