# How to get Collection Data from firestore

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I am using firestore

I have health name collection

```
collection health
doc customername
collection customerinfo  // multiple
doc customerwardinfo
```

Code:

```
firebase.firestore()
        .collection("health")
        .doc('customername')
        .get()
        .then((data)=>{            
            console.log("customer data",data);
        })
```

i am using the above code but not getting data. i want to use for each for some sub collections. but i am not able to implement it. how i will get all data. suppose a collection has 10 docs. then use foreach for each doc and get data from each doc.

Comment: If you're asking how to get a list of all subcollections of a specific document, that is not possible with the client-side SDKs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596532/how-to-list-subcollections-in-a-cloud-firestore-document

Answer (score 0):

.doc().get() does NOT return a promise of the Document; it returns a promise of a DocumentSnapshot, which contains a great deal MORE than just the document.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot

As you can see, DocumentSnapshot has properties "exists", "metadata", "id" and "ref", and methods "data()" [which returns an object with the document fields - the data], "get()" [which can return specified fields from the document], and "isEqual()", which can compare DocumentSnapshots.

on .doc().get().get() - while the final result would be only the requested fields, the entire document is fetched from the database/store.

As  Frank van Puffelen mentions, there is no way to retrieve a list of sub-collections - Firestore does NOT enforce or document your schema; that's *your* job as a developer.

Tracy Hall