# Firestore sub-collections id

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way I can get the ID for a sub-collection in firestore? I've made an application which works if I type in the sub-collection's ID manually, so I want to avoid this.

In the picture I've added the 403p2bY..... is the user.uid and I can refer it using the same. But as for the wallet id, I need to manually enter the id. Is there any way to solve this?Thank you !

[image: My code]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, as both of the collection names (`users` and `wallet`) seems fixed in your case. Are you trying to get all the `wallet` documents for a known user?

Comment: Yes.
db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get().then(doc => {...})    \\ This is working fine
db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('wallet').doc('iMsV7wV1lZIyekKrv6Gr').get().then( doc => {...}) \\ Instead of hard-coding the wallet id in this line, is there any in built function to get the wallet id.
Yes, I'm trying to get wallet documents for a specific user. I want this to be a general process since I don't want to type in the wallet id every time I want some documents for a unique user.

Comment: `db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('wallet').get()` will get you all wallet documents, and then you can loop over the results and print `doc.id` to get each id. Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all wallet documents for the user with `db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('wallet').get()`, and then you can loop over the results and print `doc.id` to get each id:

```
db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('wallet').get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  });
});
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [getting all documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection).

Answer (score 0):

Subcollection names work just like top-level collection names: you have to know the name in order to work with it.  If you don't know the name, you won't be able to query the documents in it.  The mobile client SDKs also don't provide any way to list the subcollections, so [you would need backend code to do that for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596532/how-to-list-subcollections-in-a-cloud-firestore-document).

If you aren't able to know the name of a subcollection for querying, then maybe a subcollection isn't the best way to organize your data.