# Filter and get all sub-collections by using where clause in Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

In firestore I have some sub-collections inside each collection just like below:

`Collection1 -> id -> Sub-collection -> scId -> Data`

So here I want to get all data from sub-collections by the help of the `where` clause. I tried one query like the below which is failing.

```
 db.collection("Collection1").whereEqualTo("eDate", selectedDate)
                    .get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                List<Exp> mData = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(Exp.class);
```

Here `eDate` is coming under the `Data` which is inside each sub-collection.
So is there any way to do that or any suggestions on how to do that or about the mistakes which I did here?

Answer (score 2):

Firestore queries are shallow and do not extend above or below the named collection being queried.  The query you show here will only return documents immediately within "Collection1".  It will not consider any documents in nested subcollections.

If you want documents in a subcollection, you will have to build a CollectionReference to that subcollection, and query it individually.  You can't query all subcollection nested under a document at the same time.  You can't query across differently-named subcollections at the same time.

If this behavior does not meet the needs of your app, you should consider restructuring your data to do so, or building your app to perform as many queries as needed to get all the documents from among all the collections where they live.

Comment: Thanks Doug. Is it possible for you to give a small example how to build a CollectionReference to that subcollection, and query it individually. i mean some clue or any link if you have in which I will get some help.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone facing the same problem in 2023,

More info about  [sub collections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#node.js_8)

Below code is in  Dart

```
    var query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Collection1');

    query
   .get()
   .where('filed', isEqualTo: value)
   .then((Collection1s) {
      Collection1s.docs.forEach((Collection1) {
      print(Collection1.get('id'));
   
     query
        .doc(Collection1.id)
        .collection('Sub-collection')
        .get()
        .then((Sub-collections) {
          Sub-collections.docs.forEach((Sub-collection) {
           print(Sub-collections.data().toString());
      });
    });
  });
});
```