# How to list all collections in firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2

I want to fetch all sub collections in my doc in angular 11. the method listCollections() is not working.

```
const snapshot = await this.firestore.collection("companies").doc(this.id).listCollections().valueChanges();
    snapshot.subscribe(val=> this.data.push(val))
    console.log(this.data);
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: The `listCollections` method is only available in the server-side SDKs of Firebase, like the one for Node.js. It is not available in the client-side SDKs, like the one for JavaScript that runs in the browser. You'll have to either hard-code knowledge of the collections in your app (most common), or expose them from server-side code to your Angular app yourself. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596532/how-to-list-subcollections-in-a-cloud-firestore-document