# Firestore Query Subcollections path

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

How to write Query subcollections to show data from FirestoreRecyclerAdapter?

I thought I read that you can query subcollections with the new Firebase Firestore, but I don't see any examples. For example I have my Firestore setup in the following way:

[image: See DEMO MY DB]

```
   -Admin[collection]

      -User Id[Document]

         -Actions [collection]

              -post id [Document]
    
                   -Action post
```

Comment: What exactly would like to query?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a query within any collection so long as the path to that collection resolves to one. This structure with firestore is always `collection/document/collection/document` as you have displayed.

You cannot however query *for* collections as they must be known through some ulterior reference on the client, such as being nested inside a dedicated document that contains a reference to each sub-collection.

For clarity, you are able to list them from the admin-sdk which requires either cloud functions or a dedicated server.

Additional: [How to list subcollections in a Cloud Firestore document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596532/how-to-list-subcollections-in-a-cloud-firestore-document)