# Get real-time updates on specific nested data in Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble getting real-time updates on data stored in Firebase Firestore, the data is organized in the following structure: MsgStatuses -> GroupId -> MessageId -> UserId(data).

I am trying to get a snapshot of changes when there is a change in GroupId and MessageId. I have tried using the following code, but it is not working:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const collectionRef = db.collection("MsgStatuses").doc("176")

collectionRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
  console.log("Data has changed:", snapshot.data());
});
```

I would like to know how to correctly get the snapshot of changes in GroupId and MessageId in Firebase Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

Read operations (including realtime listeners) in Firestore are shallow; so reading document `/MsgStatuses/176` does not then also read the subcollections under it.

If you want to listen to a specific message for a specific group ID, you will need to know that message ID, and then listen for:

```
const collectionRef = db.collection("MsgStatuses").doc("176").collection("your message ID");

collectionRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data());
  })
});
```

For more on this, also see the documentation on [listening for multiple documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection).

---

As said above, you will need to know the message ID for this to be possible. The client-side SDKs for Firestore have no API to get a list of all subcollections under a path. For more on this, see: [How to list subcollections in a Cloud Firestore document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596532/how-to-list-subcollections-in-a-cloud-firestore-document)

If you can't know the message ID, you'll want to consider changing your data model so that *either* you can know the message ID (e.g. by storing it in the parent document), *or* so that the messages are stored as documents: `/MsgStatuses/$groupId/messages/$messageId`. So with this structure, you can listen for all messages for a group with:

```
db.collection("MsgStatuses").doc("176").collection("messages")
```

Comment: Hi @Frank thanks for your answer updates on single messages works fine. I am looking for a way to get updates on multiple messages in Firestore. Specifically, I want to get updates on all documents within a specific collection, or on an array of specific message IDs. Can you provide an example of how to do this?

Comment: If you want to listen for updates to an entire collection, call `onSnapshot` in the `CollectionReference` rather than on a `DocumentReference`. What happens when you try that?

Comment: I have a collection of message IDs in Firebase Firestore and each message ID has a document with a group ID. I am currently using the onSnapshot method to listen to changes for each message ID, but it is causing performance issues on Android due to too many calls. Is there a way to pass an array of message IDs to the CollectionReference or listen to the snapshot of a DocumentRef, instead of iterating through each message ID individually?

Comment: The only options are to either listen to one specific collection at a path you know, or for all collections with a given name using a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).